# How do you get the instance of the imported object after importing with django-import-export?

Tags: django-admin, django-import-export

I'm trying to add objects to a related model after importing using [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

### My Models

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class EventSession(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sessions")
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

### My Import Data

| id | start_date | start_time | minutes | sessions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 9/1/21 | 10:00 | 60 | 2 |
|  | 9/8/21 | 10:00 | 60 | 3 |

### My ModelResource Class

I am trying to override `after_import_row` to get the imported event and then create
the event sessions, but I don't know how to get the imported event.

```
class EventResource(resources.ModelResource):

    start_date = fields.Field()
    start_time = fields.Field()

    def after_import_row(self, row, row_result, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        """ After importing the row, get the saved event and save the event sessions."""
        
        event = get_instance() # HOW TO GET THE INSTANCE????

        start_datetime = timezone.make_aware(
            datetime.combine(row["start_date"], row["start_time"])
        )
        end_datetime = start_datetime + timedelta(minutes=row["minutes"])
        first_session = EventSession(
            event=event,
            start_date=start_datetime,
            end_date=end_datetime,
        )
        first_session.save()

        for _ in range(1, row["sessions"]):
            # Sessions are always consecutive days
            start_datetime = start_datetime + timedelta(days=1)
            end_datetime = end_datetime + timedelta(days=1)
            event_session = EventSession(
              event=event,
              start_date=start_datetime,
              end_date=end_datetime,
            )
            event_session.save()

        return super().after_import_row(
            row, row_result, row_number=row_number, **kwargs
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            "id",
            "title",
            "start_date",
            "start_time",
            "sessions",
        )
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. I can save the instance as an attribute of the `EventResource` object by overriding `after_save_instance()`.

```
def after_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
    self.instance = instance
    return super().after_save_instance(instance, using_transactions, dry_run)
```

Then in `after_import_row()`, I use:

```
event = self.instance
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get hold of the instance id as follows:

```py
def after_import_row(self, row, row_result, row_number=None, **kwargs):
    print(row_result.object_id)
```

Obviously you can then load the object if required.

An alternative is to override `after_import()`.  In this case, the `result` object passed to the method contains `rows`, which is a list of all imported rows.

```py
def after_import(self, dataset, result, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
    for row_result in result:
        print(row_result.object_id)
```

Comment: That's nice. I now see that `object_id` is set in `import_row`, but I'd love to know how you figured that out. As far as I can tell, it's undocumented (https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_results.html).

Comment: had to look into the code. I'll raise an issue to improve the docs here.